# Video Sequencer Preview Isn't Playing Grease Pencil Animation Strips

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, grease-pencil, 2d

I looked around for someone else that had my issue, but I didn't see anything. I'm very new to Blender, so maybe I just set something up wrong.

Anyways, here's the problem. I have several grease pencil animated scenes in Blender. I've added these scenes to the video sequencer and they show up fine in the video sequencer preview too. It scrubs fine when I pull the cursor back and forth and it shows the grease pencil scenes. However, when I play the video sequencer it only shows one frame from the sequence while the video plays. Even when it flips to the next scene it still stays on the same frame. The correct frame shows up when I pause the video or scrub the timeline. But it's always stuck on one frame when I try to play it.

Maybe it's my settings? I have no idea. Can't seem to find a solution to it. I also have a quick screen recording showing the issue I see, and I uploaded the [Blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aWmXjpUdoN6kS3r3Qp5UexshN0qgVzqh/view?usp=sharing) for anyone that wants to poke around it.

[image]

Thanks so much in advance! I'm loving the program so far.

Comment: May not be a problem, or a minor bug. If rendering results were screwy, however, then something’s seriously wrong. For now, check things like the view settings for the sequence editor.

Comment: tried your file and whilst the preview doesn't update by default, I noticed that when pressing play with the mouse over the preview panel, then it updates fine. it does sound like a bug to me

Comment: @wilks That works for me! I was able to get it to play when I did what you said. It isn't perfect but I'll take it!! Thanks so much ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@wilks gave me the answer. When playing the video, hover your mouse over the preview window and then press play. It works when you do that.